# Adding properties for a bean

Tags: java, spring

I have following bean class. I want to define this bean into the xml file.

I want to know which objects of this bean are added as a property of the bean in the xml?

```
     public class Mybean{
        public String name;
        public String address;

        public String getName()
        {
          return name;
        }

       public void setName(String name)
       {
         this.name=name;
       }

       public String getAddress()
       {
          return address;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have getters and setters for the name and address fields they can both serve as properties.

```
<bean id="mybean" class="package.to.MyBean">
   <property name="name" value="something"/>
   <property name="address" value="something"/>
</bean>
```

Reference: http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-basic-setter-injection.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the answer is in order to set an object as a property, you need to have both getter and setter methods. If you read carefully in the above code addres does not have a setter method. So in that case it cannot be set as a property. Please tell me if I am right.

Comment: @ParagA Your exactly right, getters and setters are required for setter injection, so address would not qualify, however there is constructor injection which would allow you to set the `address` field. I misread the code and didn't see that it did not include a setter for `address`

Answer (score 0):

Let your class implement InitializingBean, then in the afterPropertiesSet() method, you can check which property has been set by spring